# How to train neural network incrementally in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Suppose I have very big train set so that Matlab hangs while training or there is insufficient memory to hold train set.

Is it possible to split the training set into parts and train the network by parts?

Is it possible to train the network with one sample at a time (one by one)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just manually divide dataset into batches and train them one after one:

```
for bn = 1:num_batches
    inputs = <get batch bn inputs>;
    targets = <get batch bn targets>;
    net = train(net, inputs, targets);
end
```

Though batch size should be greater than 1, but anyway that should reduce memory consumtion for training.

In case of `trainlm` training alogrithm, `net.efficiency.memoryReduction` optim could help.
Also instead of default `trainlm` algorithm you can try less memory consuming ones like `trainrp`.
For details on training algorithms check [matlab documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/train-the-network.html).
I assumed above that you are using corresponding matlab toolbox for neural networks.

Regarding training one sample at a time you could try googling for stochastic gradient descent algorithm. But, it looks like it is not in default set of training algorithm in the toolbox.

Comment: In each iteration wouldn't be write over the previous "net" and over writes over it?

Comment: @Avatar First call of `train` will create initial weights for `net` and train a batch starting from them. But all subsequent calls would start training from weights obtained after training network on previous batches. So usually one should expect overall increase of network accuracy.

Comment: What do you mean by train a batch? like 100 portion of data per training? Instead of train shouldn't we use adapt() function?
In my experiments I observe that when I iteratively train the data, the weight start to take the shape of the training portion of the data and over-writes into weights which are already trained before. I couldn't able to overcome this problem. Do you have any advice related to that?