# How can I train neural network with more data than can fit the memory?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, bigdata

Trying to train a classifier with a recurrent layer using a lot of data. As a result, all data can not fit into the memory. It provides me with the following error:

```
Error using zeros
Requested 1x2114046976 (15.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long
time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.
Error in nnMex.perfsGrad (line 3)
TEMP = zeros(1,ceil(hints.tempSizeBG/8)*8);
Error in nnCalcLib/perfsGrad (line 294)
                lib.calcMode.perfsGrad(calcNet,lib.calcData,lib.calcHints);
Error in trainscg>initializeTraining (line 153)
[worker.perf,worker.vperf,worker.tperf,worker.gWB,worker.gradient] = calcLib.perfsGrad(calcNet);
Error in nnet.train.trainNetwork>trainNetworkInMainThread (line 28)
worker = localFcns.initializeTraining(archNet,calcLib,calcNet,tr);
Error in nnet.train.trainNetwork (line 16)
    [archNet,tr] = trainNetworkInMainThread(archNet,rawData,calcLib,calcNet,tr,feedback,localFcns);
Error in trainscg>train_network (line 147)
[archNet,tr] = nnet.train.trainNetwork(archNet,rawData,calcLib,calcNet,tr,localfunctions);
Error in trainscg (line 59)
            [out1,out2] = train_network(varargin{2:end});
Error in network/train (line 369)
    [net,tr] = feval(trainFcn,'apply',net,data,calcLib,calcNet,tr);
```

It should be noted that currently my training input is 11x52266 and the network has ~3k weight elements due to the recurrent layer. I would like, however, to provide 15 times as much data for training.

How can I cope? Are there any techniques to map the local variable it's trying to initialize on my SSD instead of memory?

There is the "reduction" option for training, but it does not seem to do any difference on this matter. The same error occurs regardless.

Comment: Disclaimer: i'm not a matlab user: Is your feature-size 11 or 52266? (in my opinion the usual format is samples X features) Why does some internal array grow with the product of your data AND the weights (this does not make sense to me; the network-weights/data-dimensions are not dependent on the sample-size (except for batch-size), maybe it's possible if internally some full-batch=full-gradient algorithm as LBGFS is used; but this would make this kind of data-size impossible; you need SGD-based methods)? Well-designed libs support some fit_on_batch method (not sure what your lib supports).

Comment: And the strategy of using SSD instead of RAM doesn't sound promising. This is hard to abstract internally, so it is not likely that your software supports it. And it would be way too slow too i think. (and i still think something else is the matter here; see other comment)

Comment: @sascha I would agree with you on that one, but Matlab's neural net implementation supports features x samples. The answer of user20160 and my comment might clarify and suggest a solution, but the Matlab has implementation for: (next comment)

Comment: 1. BFGS quasi-Newton backpropagation
2. Scaled conjugate gradient backpropagation
3. Conjugate gradient backpropagation with Powell-Beale restarts
4. Conjugate gradient backpropagation with Fletcher-Reeves updates
5. Conjugate gradient backpropagation with Polak-Ribiére updates
6. Gradient descent with adaptive learning rate backpropagation
7. Gradient descent with momentum backpropagation
8. Gradient descent with momentum and adaptive learning rate backpropagation
9. One-step secant backpropagation
10. Resilient backpropagation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if your dataset is too big to fit into memory, you'll have to process it in chunks. For training large networks, it's typical to use stochastic gradient descent (which only requires access to a single data point at a time), or minibatch training (which only requires access to the data points in the minibatch). Besides requiring less memory, these methods also tend to converge much faster than batch gradient descent (which uses the entire dataset for each weight update). Disk access is slow so, even though only a few data points are required per update, you should still load as many points as you can, then split them into minibatches, etc. There are other tricks you can play to reduce the number of disk reads, like performing multiple updates before loading the next set of data.

Another point is specific to recurrent neural networks (RNNs). When you train a RNN using backpropagation through time (BPTT), the network has to be 'unrolled' in time, and is treated as a very deep feedforward network with a copy of the recurrent layer at each time step. This means that performing BPTT over more timesteps requires more memory (and more computation time). A solution is to use truncated BPTT, where the gradient is only propagated back over a fixed number of time steps.

Comment: Thank you, @user20160. It seems I will need to process the data in chunks with the strategy being selecting a mini-batch duration of M (for the training of sequences) and then have N mini-batches in a chunk, yes? Matlab should have support for this. [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628280/how-to-train-neural-network-incrementally-in-matlab?rq=1 ]

It seems that Matlab does not support SGD for learning (currently using SCG; scaled conjugate gradient). It has been suggested to use resilient backpropagation - RP - is that necessary with minibatch training?

Comment: If your data is sequences, you'd load a chunk of data into memory containing some number of minibatches. Each minibatch will contain multiple sequences. If the minibatch contains a single sequence, then you're doing SGD. Conjugate gradient methods typically work in batch mode. There might be a way to use it w/ large minibatches, but you'd have to look into it carefully. Can't comment on whether Rprop would be good or not, but it's certainly not *necessary* to use.

Comment: I can make each mini-batch be 1 complete sequence, and then have each batch being several mini-batches. I guess I would need an amount of samples, say I=(number of time delays in network), to begin each mini-batch where the error is not evaluated?

Comment: "and then have each batch being several mini-batches" Well, you'd have a bunch of minibatches in memory (each containing some number of sequences, possibly one), and train on a single minibatch at a time. "I would need an amount of samples...to begin each mini-batch where the error is not evaluated?" The error is generally evaluated at all points if you have an output at every timestep. If using truncated BPTT, you'd update the weights after running through some fixed number of timesteps.

Comment: Regarding the "error": I have the possibility of adding error weights, to disregard specific samples from learning. I could set error weight to 0 for the initial I samples in a mini-batch, so it does not hinder learning.